# MacOS SwiftUI reduce the size of the Picker

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, picker

Result I would like to achieve:
[image]

Result I get:
[image]

As you can see from the images, in the first image the Picker is much smaller (Size of the darts, maybe you don't notice that much, but that's what's on xcode).

This is the code I am using:

```swift
Picker("", selection: $inspectorModel.indentUsingSelection) {
            ForEach(inspectorModel.indentUsingList) {
                Text($0.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 11))
            }
}
.labelsHidden()
```

Can you give me a hand?